# How can I splice two list by append

Tags: java, list

I tried:

```
List splice(List l1, List l2){
    List l3 = new LinkedList();
    return l3;
}

List append(List l1, List l2) {
    List to_return = copy(l1);
    List l3 = copy(l2);
    while (true) {
        if (l3.isEmpty())
            return to_return;
        to_return = append1(to_return,hd(l3));
        l3 = tl(l3);
    }
}
```

What should I do next? If I input `[1,2,3]` and `[a,b]`, I want to get `[1,a,2,b,3]`.

Comment: You want to alternate the items? Are you sure that's what you need? You don't want a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) or something?

Comment: I think this is better known as interleaving. Splicing involves the ends.

Comment: I'm guessing he doesn't want a map since it looks like his lists might not be equal.  If he's trying to create a map, dictionary, or some other key value pair, he would probably want equal lists, right?

Besides needing to add the append to your splice (since it just returns an empty list right now), you'll probably want to create a loop that alternately iterates through each list and adds each index to the to_return list.  They way you're doing it right now... probably doesn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java: Interleave two integer based arraylists -> good approach?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551670/java-interleave-two-integer-based-arraylists-good-approach)

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand your code, but you say

> If I input [1,2,3] and[a,b], I want to get[1,a,2,b,3].

This can be achieved by

```
static <T> List<T> interleave(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
    List<T> newList = new ArrayList<T>();
    List<T> shortOne = list1.size() < list2.size() ? list1 : list2;
    List<T> longOne  = list1.size() < list2.size() ? list2 : list1;
    for (int i = 0; i < shortOne.size(); i++) {
        newList.add(list1.get(i));
        newList.add(list2.get(i));
    }
    for (int i = shortOne.size(); i < longOne.size(); i++) {
        newList.add(longOne.get(i));
    }
    return newList;
}
```

**EDIT**

Depending on the `List` implementation you are using, the approach of the accepted answer in this post may be more efficient: [Java: Interleave two integer based arraylists -> good approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14551670/java-interleave-two-integer-based-arraylists-good-approach)

Comment: The only problem here is the use of `get(int index)` method, if OP sends `LinkedList` this method would be O(n^2).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: That's correct. Any idea how to circumvent this?

Comment: Use iterators as proposed in the answer of the possible duplicate question.

Comment: Yes, that solution is better than what I posted.